# MASK(...) macro with undefined number of arguments (in C)

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor

(Sorry for bad english.)

I need macro `MASK` such that:

- `MASK(a)` expands to `(1<<(a))`
- `MASK(a,b)` expands to `(1<<(a) | 1<<(b))`
- `MASK(a,b,c)` expands to `(1<<(a) | 1<<(b) | 1<<(c))`
- etc.

Is it possible to define such macro in C preprocessor? Maybe can help some GCC extensions? Or maybe is it possible to implement `MASK(x)` with single argument such that `MASK((a,b))` expands to `(1<<(a) | 1<<(b))`, etc.

**ADDED.** I'm not interested as implement `MASK` as a function.

Comment: Is your requirement that the macro expands exactly that way (in other words, it generates a constant), or would it be ok if expands to a function call? The latter can be done with a C99 variadic macro.

Comment: @Chris: I'm know that I can implement `MASK` as inline function with `...`. Moreover, I think good compilers like GCC optimize the call as it will be explictly written `(1<<(a))|...`. So, I'm interesting only with *preprocessor*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, without any extensions, assuming a near-fully C99 compliant preprocessor, such as GNU CPP (as used by GCC/G++).

Here are a few different solutions using the brilliant [Order](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Order) library. You will need to add `#include <order/interpreter.h>` to use them.

With just one `#define`:

```
#define MASK(...) (ORDER_PP(8seq_for_each_with_delimiter( \
    8fn(8N, 8print((1<<) 8tuple(8N))), \
    8emit(8quote(|)), \
    8tuple_to_seq(8quote((__VA_ARGS__))))))
```

For compiler speed and maintainability:

```
#define GEN_MASK(x) 1<<(x)
#define ORDER_PP_DEF_8mask ORDER_PP_FN(8fn(8N, \
    8emit(8quote(GEN_MASK),8tuple(8N))))
#define MASK(...) (ORDER_PP(\
    8seq_for_each_with_delimiter(8mask, 8emit(8quote(|)), \
    8tuple_to_seq(8quote((__VA_ARGS__))))))
```

Using a generalisation for similar problems:

```
#define MAP_DELIMITED(f,d, ...) ORDER_PP(\
    8seq_for_each_with_delimiter(f, \
    8emit(8quote(d)), \
    8tuple_to_seq(8quote((__VA_ARGS__)))))
#define MASK(...) (MAP_DELIMITED( \
    8fn(8N, 8print((1<<) 8tuple(8N))), \
    |, \
    __VA_ARGS__))
```

Order actually implements a high level functional language within the preprocessor, allowing much more complex macros than you would think possible. The repo in the above link includes many examples and the source to the documentation.